# setOnItemClickListener returns the first element

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView populated by ArrayList. When I click on a element of the LV in my view the application starts a new Activity.
But if I click on the second or third element of the listview, it is as if I had pressed the first one. Here's some code:

```
RipartitoriRepo repo = new RipartitoriRepo(this);
        my_list = repo.getRipartitoriByIdUnitàAbitativa(IdUnitàAbitativa);
        if(my_list.size()!=0){

            my_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

                    TextView my_textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IdElementCell);
                    String myId = my_textview.getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra("IdElement", myId);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            SimpleAdapter adapter;
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, my_list, R.layout.ripartitori_row, new String[]{"idripartitore","posizione", "matricola", "altezza", "larghezza"},
                    new int[]{R.id.IdRipartitore_cell,R.id.ripart_posizione, R.id.ripart_matricola, R.id.rip_altezza, R.id.rip_larghezza});

            my_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

And here's the cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/IdElement_cell"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rip_testo1"
            android:text="Posizione:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rip_testo1"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:textSize="20dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/ripart_posizione"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Matricola:"
            android:id="@+id/rip_testo4"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ripart_matricola"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rip_testo4"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rip_testo2"
            android:text="Altezza:"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rip_testo2"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:id="@+id/rip_altezza"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rip_altezza"
            android:text="Larghezza:"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/rip_testo3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rip_larghezza"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rip_testo3"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For example: if the first element has `Id = 00001`and the second has `Id = 0002`, when I click on the list view, the `setOnItemClickListener`method works as if I clicked always the first element. So my_textview will be always `00001`.

Comment: you are always passing the same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find `R.id.IdElementCell` in your xml.

But my guess is, you have to do

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    ...

    TextView my_textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.IdElementCell);
    String myId = my_textview.getText().toString();

    ...
}
```

**edit**

You were trying to find your view with id R.id.IdElementCell on your activity.
Since this is a view that's part of a listItem, it has multiple instances and will return the first view found with this id.

By calling the findViewById function on the view which is clicked, we limit our search to the child views within this clicked view. Because of this, we get the correct view.

Comment: this is the solution! I miss the VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
intent.putExtra("IdElement", position);

startActivity(intent);
```

**Update**

```
 TextView my_textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IdElementCell);
 String myId = my_textview.getText().toString();
 my_textview.setTag("myId", myId);
 intent.putExtra("IdElement", my_textview.getTag("myId"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I need the content from the textview, because I have the IdElement from DB

Comment: the solution is from @snyersk

Comment: yeah but Iam not directly using text but the using tag which is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass:

```
intent.putExtra("IdElement", id); // OR position, if you don't care about ID's
```

not

```
intent.putExtra("IdElement", myId);
```

Comment: I need the content from the textview, because I have the IdElement from DB

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring a textview in your listview's onclick via following code

```
TextView my_textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IdElementCell);
String myId = my_textview.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("IdElement", myId);
```

and sending this id to your next activity it doesn't matter which position you click you are always passing the textview id with id **IdElementCell** that's why you are always retrieving the same id,you never sent different ids to get the position on which the click event has occurred you can retrieve it by position or the parameter **long id** in setOnItemClickListener() will provide you the row id of the item that was clicked.

Comment: but the content of the textview is an ID taken from a DB via query. I need that Id because in the next activity I use a method called "getElementById"

Comment: so you are always passing the same id so how will you get different id ??